# What is the alternative to rewritebase on IIS?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file in my website - I'm having to relocate it to a windows IIS machine and having problems with using the URL-Rewrite module to import a rule and create a `web.config` file.

This is my `.htaccess` file

```
# Rewrite URLs and direct to index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
##
## If moving host, change the structure below to folder name of where public folder lives
##
RewriteBase /foldername/public
##
##
##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It fails on the `RewriteBase` but this I understand in the `.htaccess` file is crucial for my site to function.

Can anyone give me anyone pointers?

Comment: What kind of site? For things like WordPress their official documentation already covers that, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/install-wordpress-on-iis#create-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will convery to below url rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <!--##-->
        <!--## If moving host, change the structure below to folder name of where public folder lives-->
        <!--##-->
        <!--##-->
        <!--##-->
        <!--##-->
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/foldername/public/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `appendQueryString="true"` (not "false") in order to be equivalent to the mod_rewrite directives in the question? Is the `/=` at the end of the second `add` condition in error?

Comment: Since the rewrite url has already added the query string, if you added it twice it will added mutiple query string.

Comment: AFAIK, the `appendQueryString` appends the query string from the _original request_ to the substitution (nothing is added "twice" here). eg. Given a request of the form `/foo?bar=1` then with `appendQueryString="false"` you'd get `/foldername/public/index.php?url=foo`. But with `appendQueryString="true"` (or omitted) you'd get `/foldername/public/index.php?url=foo&bar=1`. (?)

Comment: All right thank you for mention it. I will modify the reply.

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteBase` directive sets the URL-path for relative path *substitutions* (overriding the *directory-prefix*). So, instead of using the `RewriteBase` directive, you could simply hardcode the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` directive itself.

For example:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ /foldername/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```